# masm instruction set recourse

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, masm

Where would I be able to find a good site of link or document that details what the full instruction set of MASM is?

To give context I am currently working on a C++ project in VS2008, and I have hit a point where it would be useful to know what exactly the assembly is saying (for added context). This isn't my only reason, but it is certainly the most pressing at the moment.

Thanks for any help, hopefully I will be able to figure out the bug without the assembly, but it helps sometimes.

Comment: +1 for diving into assembly.

Comment: Thanks, its been useful for debugging some things. I have a course on it this year, but its useful now. Also here is a site where I found good info. [link](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For genuine instructions, the [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/) literature is very good. I don't know the numbers for the Intel manuals, as I have the AMD ones in "real paper" on my desk. Most of what you need will be in AMD Vol 3 (General Purpose and System instructions), but you may need the SSE Vol 4 (128 Bit Media instructions) and Vol 5 x87 (Floating point and 64-bit Media instructions) too.

I've also used [sandpile.org](http://www.sandpile.org/) as a quick reference for instructions - mainly to decode instructions from binary.

Obviously MASM also has a bunch of [directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), such as forming strings, assigning section names to different bits, designating something data or code, etc.